# Posting all checkboxes in form array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, checkbox

Hi i have a form that looks like this:

```
<div class="row calc">
<div class="large 12 columns">
        <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <input name="units[]" type="text" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>GroupNR</label>
        <input name="article_group[]" type="text" value="2401">
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <label>Item name</label>
        <input name="article[]" type="text" value="Item 1">
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input name="description_en[]" type="text" value="Description 1">
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Price/Unit</label>
        <input name="unit_price[]" type="text" value="15500">
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Discount</label>
        <input max="100" min="0" name="discount[]" type="number" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Invoice</label>
        <input checked="checked" name="invoice[]" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>D. Note</label>
        <input checked="checked" name="delivery_note[]" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <label>Delete</label>
        <a class="alert button tiny" onclick="$(this).closest('.calc').remove(); $( '#itemForm' ).trigger('change');">X</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

These inputs get added dynamically (with Jquery) as rows, and there could be one or there could be 10, 20 you name it.

The problem is that when i submit these to php, i have no way of knowing which rows have the "invoice" and "D.note" checkboxes checked or unchecked, because the array i'm recieving looks like this

```
 array:13 [▼
  "units" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  "article_group" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2401"
    1 => "2201"
    2 => "2503"
  ]
  "article" => array:3 [▶]
  "description_en" => array:3 [▶]
  "unit_price" => array:3 [▶]
  "discount" => array:3 [▶]
  "invoice" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "on"
    1 => "on"
  ]
  "delivery_note" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "on"
    1 => "on"
  ]
]
```

But really, it is row "0" and "2" that are checked, and row "1" unchecked.

This is how i iterate through it in php/laravel

```
for($i=0;$i<count($items['units']);$i++){
        $bookdetails = new BookingDetails;
        $bookdetails->article_group = $items['article_group'][$i];
        $bookdetails->article = $items['article'][$i];
        $bookdetails->description_en = $items['description_en'][$i];
        $bookdetails->units = $items['units'][$i];
        $bookdetails->unit_price = $items['unit_price'][$i];
        $bookdetails->discount = $items['discount'][$i];
        $bookdetails->show_invoice = $items['invoice'][$i];
        $bookdetails->show_picklist = $items['delivery_note'][$i];
        $bookdetails->save();
    }
```

So is there a way to submit the unchecked boxes aswell?
Having a hidden input with the same name wont work since i use array without set index, maybe i can make my ajax call send a number to index the array, but there has to be a easier solution

Or does anyone have a suggestion for another solution?

Regards Johan

Comment: why do you tag jquery to this question?

Comment: jquery is used to dynamically add the inputs to the dom, and i would use it to send a number if i need to index the array @Jai

Comment: yeah, you need to add indexes to each set of elements `units[0]`, `article_group[0]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some possibilities to solve this issue with JavaScript:

- either instead of using `name="delivery_note[]"`, you create an enumeration : `name="delivery_note_1"` (and in your PHP code, you loop until they don't exist)
- **or as @billyonecan suggests `name="delivery_note[1]"`** *(solution used by the asker)*
- or *onsubmit* (JS event, that you can easily capture with jquery) you do some treatment to insert in the checkbox array some other (default) values for the unchecked checkboxes

Comment: I changed my ajax query to add indexes, and that worked, thanks!

Comment: I noticed a problem, that maybe you have a solution for. I can remove input rows with the delete button, and this breaks the iteration because the count is something like 3, but i have [0],[1],[3],[4],[6]. This gives me an illegal offset [2] error. Thanks

Comment: Which solution did you choose? In your PHP code, you could do `foreach($items['units'] as $i => $unit)` and use the $i as index

Comment: Yes, but then it would loop through `$items['units']` first, and i need to save every input with the same index as a row in the DB. Or am i missing sonething? I did like you and @billyonecan, and added indexes to the inputs

Comment: When you simply replace your `for` line with this one: `foreach(array_keys($items['units']) as $i)`: the `$i` (the key) will only have the actually affected values (ie the one you need).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a unique value to each checkbox. Then you can use the value to identify the checkbox

Checker:

```
<?php

        foreach($_POST['check'] as $k){

            // Value of checkbox that are checked
            echo $k; 
        }
    ?>
```

Form:

```
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='2'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='3'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='4'>
</form>
```